# Why I couldn`t create jar file with module in console but when added space and dot at the end of console query it worked?

Tags: java

I try to create jar with module in windows terminal

I tried this command
`jar --create --file=mymodapp\applib\appfuncs.jar  -С mymodapp\ appmodules\appfuncs`
it give the error "Error parsing file arguments"

But when i try
`jar --create --file=mymodapp\applib\appfuncs.jar  -С mymodapp\ appmodules\appfuncs .`
(space and dot at the end) it works fine.Why?

Comment: The syntax is `jar [OPTION ...] [ [--release VERSION] [-C dir] files]` - so while the `-C` changes the directory it stills requires a `files` specification.

Comment: The space here separates arguments in the command and `.` represents the current directory.